The monad induced by the group multiplication
Let $G$ be any group. We can define its delooping, $\mathbf{B}G$, to be the groupoid with a single object $\bullet$ and $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf BG}(\bullet, \bullet) = G$ with composition given by the group multiplication.
Take now any $g\in G$ and consider an inner group automorphism $T\colon G\to G$ given by $T(h)=g^{-1}hg$. We can treat it as an endofunctor of $\mathbf{B}G$.
This functor is naturally isomorphic to the identity functor $1_{\mathbf BG}$ via the natural isomorphism with a single component $g^{-1}\colon \bullet\to \bullet$.
It looks to me that $T$ is a monad, when we use $g^{-1}$ as the unit $\eta\colon 1_{\mathbf BG}\Rightarrow T$ and $g$ as the multipication $\mu\colon T^2\Rightarrow T$.
Verifying the conditions was tedious, but conceptually easy: I however do not understand what this monad "does".
Large majority of monads I have heard of allow one to define new kinds of objects (such as the $\mathrm{Maybe}$ monad or the ones arising from free-forgetful adjunctions), with exceptions of the identity monad and closure operators (which are monads on a partial order interpreted as a category).
Hence, my (strongly connected) questions would be:

What is the "intuitive" meaning of this monad?
As $T$ is naturally isomorphic to $1_{\mathbf{B}G}$, can this monad be interpreted in terms of the identity monad?

I am also quite convinced that this has been already studied (however I did not find mentions of this topic on nLab, Wikipedia, or Google), so reference suggestions would be more than welcome!

$T$ is isomorphic to the identity monad on $\mathbf{B}G$. More generally, if $(T, \eta, \mu)$ is a monad then $\eta : 1 \to T$ is a morphism of monads (as witnessed by the diagrams below), and if $\eta$ is invertible then it is an isomorphism of monads.

